# Two parallel increment and decrement terminating when equal

Tags: java, scala, parallel-processing

Let's say you have the following two procedures:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 10;
def P = { while (x != y) x = x + 1; }
def Q = { while (x != y) y = y - 1; }
```

Run both in parallel.

The only atomic operations are READ, INCREMENT, DECREMENT, WRITE.

I would imagine there is a case where one process "skips over" the other (since you don't control how they are run).

Here is an example:

- P and Q READ x = 0, y = 10 (the very beginning)
- Q runs quickly and makes y reach 0
- P INCREMENTS and WRITES and now x is 1 (since it still thinks y is 10)
- back to Q, READ x as 1 and y as 0
- Q decrements y to -1
- Never terminate

Why doesn't that happen? it seems like it ALWAYS terminates.

Can someone explain why my example doesn't happen?

Comment: Increment and decrement are atomic? Not on the JVM, I don't believe. Not even if your code compiles to *iinc*. Reading from RAM, computing a new value and writing it back are never atomic.

Comment: @RandallSchulz eh, I separate increment/decrement from read and write.

Comment: You may want to think of them that way, but it is not so. Increment and decrement are a read followed by a write and fundamentally *not* atomic. To perhaps clarify, the incrementing itself happens only in processor registers.

Comment: @RandallSchulz my question is indeed very poor because I didn't show the complete implementation. However, regarding your comment, I think you can't see my point. I said many times that I separate read and write from incrementing and decrementing. That's actually what you are saying "they happen in the processor registers", yes EXACTLY. a "complete" increment, I defined it as, read + incrememnt_in_processor + write. Each one of these three are atomic, so the overall complete increment is obviously not atomic.

Comment: The very concept of atomicity is about what can be observed between one thread of execution and another or between one processor and another. Actions occurring strictly within a processor are by definition outside such observation. So "increment" and "decrement" are, by definition, either not atomic or irrelevant to atomicity. But they are *not* atomic!

Comment: @RandallSchulz so they are essentially "steps" that I can use in this context to illustrate the process in terms of single actions that cannot be broken down. I think I did it justice, you are rather being pedantic in an anti-productive sense.

Comment: You started out with "The only atomic operations are READ, INCREMENT, DECREMENT, WRITE." I objected to this statement, since it simply is not true. You can play with the semantics all you want, but you will not be correct. ... And the word is "counterproductive."

Comment: @RandallSchulz Thanks ! English is not my native. I will remember this word.

Answer (score 2):

I was first going to downvote this question but it gave me mixed feelings because on one hand it's not a well phrased question: what concurrency framework do you use? Are you sure you are doing the right thing - is it truly concurrent? How can we tell without seeing more code. What are these assumptions about atomicity? Do you physically run this on a single thread in some sort of VM where there is no true concurrency? How do I know all this? Are you really running only until a count of 10? Do I even care? Should I care? ...

... but then I though I should point this out:

Does this loop terminate?:

```
var x = 1; while(x>0){ x = x + 1 }
```

Or a similar question - what's the value of `Int.MaxValue + 1`?

That's a partial answer to your question... the other part I don't quite care about ;)

Answer (score 0):

I like your question in general, but you have to provide the real soure code so that we can help. One possible answer is optimization. Value of y in the P loop can be "cached" in a  processor register and doesn't have to contain current value from memory.

In Java you can solve this issue by the `volatile` keyword:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

In Scala there is a volatile annotation:
http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7952.html

Try to add `println(y)` to the P loop so that you see whether (and how) value of y changes. Keep on trying.